# What does number placed next to bar chart in Table of Contents by ArcGIS for Desktop mean?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, chart

Working with [bar charts in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000003000000) 10.2.1

What does the 0.22 represent on the chart symbology in the Table of Contents?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is in the resources.arcgis.com web page. See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000034000000 for details. But the number represents...

> "the attribute value for a chart symbol of that size on the map. For
>   example, a value of 5 means a chart on the map that is the same size
>   as the chart in the table of contents represents 5 data units.
>   Similarly, a chart on the map that is twice as big as the chart in the
>   table of contents represents 10 data units. The chart symbol and value
>   in the table of contents also appear in the legend."

Comment: So, because I don't think this is clear. Lets say 0.22 is the value next to your chart. That means the chart will appear as size 0.22, based on whatever map units you are using in the map (e.g. meters, decimal degrees etc). If I change the chart size to 0.44 the chart will be double the size of what I see in the TOC.